# Drift and Minorization for Metropolis Hastings algorithm

Tags: metropolis-hastings

Can some one point me to articles or literature with an example of the drift and minorization condition proof. At the moment i have come across the Gibbs Sampler and the Random Walk Metropolis Hastings where the drift condition  and the corresponding minorization condition  proofs are simpler. Your help greatly appreciated.

Comment: As Roberts, Rosenthal, and Tweedie have published dozens of papers on the topic, it would help to understand what exactly is the difficulty you have in mind and to know which papers and examples you have already studied.

Comment: I have read some papers from Rosenthal and Tweedie and so far the illustrated applications are mainly on a Gibbs Sampling algorithm where the expectation of the drift function wrt to the Markov Transition density  is easier to evaluate. I would like to see the treatment in cases where the posteriors are not in closed form and the proposal density is not necessarily symmetric